# Creating a ranking number in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating a scoreboard for my gaming club and I've almost got it figured, but for some reason this function isn't changing the array as desired.

```
function sortPos($i)
{
if (($i[9])<($ado[9])) 
    $i[10] = ($i[10])+1;
if (($i[9])<($kort[9])) 
    $i[10] = ($i[10])+1;
if (($i[9])<($jay[9])) 
    $i[10] = ($i[10])+1;
if (($i[9])<($aris[9])) 
    $i[10] = ($i[10])+1;
if (($i[9])<($eddie[9])) 
    $i[10] = ($i[10])+1;
if (($i[9])<($foster[9])) 
    $i[10] = ($i[10])+1;
if (($i[9])<($alan[9])) 
    $i[10] = ($i[10])+1;
if (($i[9])<($matman[9])) 
    $i[10] = ($i[10])+1;

return $i;
}
```

The array is supposed to have a ranking score at the end and this function is supposed to check scores against the other players and adjust your rank accordingly if someone could tell me why this isn't changing the value of `$i[10]` that'd be great.

Comment: function scope. `$ado` et al are nor defined in; or passed to the function

Comment: Also you can leave the `return` statement if you pass the array as [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: @kingkero: it's a terrible advice. `return` is a natural way to return result from a function. In this case there is no reason to use references

Comment: what is $i (array? ... someting else). it is hard to understand your question. Please program things like in normal life, give your variable names that everybody can understand even if the name is long.

Comment: Show us your `sortPos()` function in the executed form with the argument you are passing. This is not JavaScript, you would have to have a lot of your variables `global` inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok firstly, let's clean this up:

```
$players = array('ado','kort','jay','aris','foster','alan','matman');

foreach($players as $name) {
  if ($i[9] < ${$name}[9]) {
      $i[10]++;
  }
}

return $i;
```

But I'm not sure why it isn't working. Perhaps scope, as was suggested, or `$i` is not an array?